# How to get full query text from performance_schema.threads?

Tags: mysql

According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/processlist-access.html#processlist-sources):

```
Access to the threads table does not require a mutex 
and has minimal impact on server  performance. The other
sources have negative performance consequences because they require a mutex.
```

So yes, I want to use threads table to examine running queries. The trouble is, the PROCESSLIST_INFO column does not contain the full query. It just contains a truncated version of the query. There is a flag viz performance_schema_max_sql_text_length which controls how many bytes are allocated for the SQL query. But it seems to affect the events_statements_history_long table. There is no change in the thread table output. There is also the events_statement_current table. But it is not clear if accessing that table affects performance or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging more into [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/5.7/en/performance-schema.html):

```
The Performance Schema is intended to provide access to 
useful information about server execution while having minimal
impact on server performance
```

It looks safe to use performance_schema.events_statement_current for monitoring currently running queries and events_statement_current.SQL_TEXT gives full query text as long as it fits performance_schema_max_sql_text_length bytes.